# Pine Script Highest and Lowest value of the prior day, including premarket & post market data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Trying to get the Highest value and Lowest Value of the prior trading day with extended hours (0400 to 2000).  For example, if the highest value happened anytime during the premarket, regular, or postmarket, I want to capture that in a variable.  The following code sort-of works, but calling the stored value seems to return zero but the line plotted works. What am I missing :(

```
// Determine prior day highest and lowest values including extended hours
i = time("1440","0400-2000") // 1440 is the number of minutes in a whole day.
is_sessionfirst = na(i[1]) and not na(i) or i[1] < i

// Define Variables
sessionhigh = float(na)
sessionlow = float(na)
prevsessionhigh = float(na)
prevsessionlow = float(na)

if is_sessionfirst and barstate.isnew and ((hour >= 0400) or (hour <= 2000))
    // If this is the first bar of the day and within premarket time range, initialize premarket values
    sessionhigh := high
    sessionlow := low
else 
    // If not the first bar, set premarket values to previous values
    sessionhigh := sessionhigh[1]
    sessionlow := sessionlow[1]

if high > sessionhigh and ((hour >= 0400) or (hour <= 2000))
    // Update premarket high if current bar's high is greater than previous premarket high and within time range
    sessionhigh := high
    
if low < sessionlow and ((hour >= 0400) or (hour <= 2000))
    // Update premarket low if current bar's low is less than previous premarket low and within time range
    sessionlow := low

if dayofweek[1] != dayofweek
    // If new trading day, update previous day's premarket high and low, using the prior premarket high and low values
    prevsessionhigh := sessionhigh[1]
    prevsessionlow := sessionlow[1]

// Plot yesterday high and low horizontal lines on the chart
plot(prevsessionhigh, style=plot.style_line, title="Yesterday PreHigh", color=#FFFFFF, linewidth=1, trackprice=true)
plot(prevsessionlow, style=plot.style_line, title="Yesterday PreLow", color=#FFFFFF, linewidth=1, trackprice=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `var` keyword if you want your variable to keep its value between each execution.

> var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
> variable.
>
> Normally, a syntax of assignment of variables, which doesn’t include
> the keyword var, results in the value of the variable being
> overwritten with every update of the data. Contrary to that, when
> assigning variables with the keyword var, they can “keep the state”
> despite the data updating, only changing it when conditions within
> if-expressions are met.

```
var prevsessionhigh = float(na)
var prevsessionlow = float(na)
```